# 'It' at the start of a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

I tend to think the following is incorrect because the 'it' that starts the second sentence refers to a noun which appeared in a previous sentence.

> The Milky Way is the name used for our own galaxy. It is 200,000 light
>   years across.

When I went to explain this to my son I became less sure that the use of 'it' should be restricted in this way . I would appreciate some ideas on this .

---

*I have looked at this previous question [How to form sentences starting with "it"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75791/how-to-form-sentences-starting-with-it) but it's too specific for my needs. I'm also aware that the list of general references should be consulted ([What good reference works on English are available?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available)) but there don't seem to be any of those which are freely available and cover this case.*

Comment: I think the "it" in your example is fine.  A bad usage would be when the noun is so far away that you forget what it was before you come to the  pronoun.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly how "It" should be used.  "It" is a pronoun and it stands in for a previously identified noun.  In your case, `The Milky Way` is the noun and, rather than repeating `The Milky Way` at the start of the second sentence, you use a shortcut of "It".  It would be less enjoyable if you wrote `The Milky Way is the name used for our own galaxy. The Milky Way is 200,000 light years across.`  Keep that up and pretty soon it won't matter because no one will be reading it.

Comment: What I'm always yelling at my kids is "Unreferenced pronoun!" when they say "It" without explaining what they talking about.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, because there are no other nouns to confuse it with, "it" is correct. However, in "I drove my car into a tree. It is broken.", "it" would not be correct as "it" could be referring to either the car or the tree.

Comment: And changing to the single sentence "... into a tree and broke it" would not remove the ambiguity.

Comment: "The Milky Way is a piece of the universe. It is 200,000 light years across."  Is another example.  "it" is working because "Milky Way" and "our galaxy" happen to be synonymous.